# Can you make a single call to the Binance API to fetch data from several endpoints?

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I am using the python-binance library, which communicates with the API.

I run a loop which frequently call for updates:

```
    result = client.futures_account_balance()
    result_account = client.futures_account()
    prices = client.futures_mark_price()
    update_a = client.futures_account_trades()
```

As you see I make 4 calls. I sometimes run this at very high frequency, so I am worried I could exceed the network limitation.

Is there a way to combine all this calls.

I can use both the binance-library or the API directly.